# Pattern not matching elements using underscore

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

This is the regex i'am currently using to match a specific word and it's variants:

```
(?:[\'"]|(?!^)\G)\h*(?:([\w.-]*\belementor\b[\w.-]*)|[\w.-]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/qwIKqw/2

This works fine, however it does not match for word including underscore e.g. "elementor_section"

I'll appreciate any hints.

Comment: Looks like `\b` are the culprits. Try https://regex101.com/r/qwIKqw/3. Replace `\belementor\b` with `(?<![^\W_])elementor(?![^\W_])`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this appear to works fine for what i'am looking for, thanks for your help !

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew please post the solution so i can accept it.